# Исключающая выборка MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, sql

Здравствуйте!
Есть 2 таблицы `register_list` (таблица с пользователями) и `orders` (таблица с заказамы).
В таблице orders есть ссылка на запись пользователя в таблице `register_list`.
Для того чтобы выбрать пользователей, которые делали заказы нужно сделать перехресную выборку и все.

А как можно одним запросом выбрать пользователей, которые НЕ делали заказы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from 
register_list as r left join orders as o
on <r.id=o.user_id>
where o.user_id is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Пользуйтесь `NOT EXISTS`